# MSTest unit test passes when in "debug" mode, but fails final assertion in "run" mode

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, race-condition, staticresource

Hi I have a unit test that goes attaches to an event and updates a counter based on a property of the eventArgs in the handler like so:

```
protected void UpdateCounts(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
  lock (lockobject)
  {
    Counts[eventArgs.Target]++;
  }
}
```

Counts is a static Dictionary resource that all unit tests in that class share. I assert that at the end of the test I assert the count to be 6 for a certain value of Target (Target is an enum). When I debug through this test, it always passes that final assertion, however, when I just run it without any breakpoints, the count for that value of Target can be 7 or 8, but never 6.

I realize that many threads trying to access an entry in a Dictionary may present a race condition, which is why I placed the lock around the increment. I also have a TestInitialize method which runs before every test gets run that looks like this:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void InitTest()
{
  foreach (TargetType x in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Target)))
  {
    Counts[x] = 0;
  }
}
```

Does anybody have any insight as to what is going on here?

Comment: So you have multiples tests running (wich is why you added the lock) at the same time? 
If that is the case: The static dictionnay is reset at  every tests and it can cause some issue since a test might have start while an other is still in the initialize

Comment: I added the lock around the increment, because I was aware that in the single test itself many threads could potentially touch the same element in the Dictionary at the same time, not because of different tests accessing it at the same time. If that was the issue, then the test wouldn't pass assertions when run in conjunction with the others, but it fails the assertions even when run just by itself. It only passes when ran in "debug" mode.

Comment: so in debug it works but not in release ?

Comment: No, sorry I think my question is unclear. In Visual Studio, in the test explorer, you have the option to run a unit test in isolation or debug a unit test in isolation. The build configuration is not related.

Comment: oh my bad okkai.  Is the problem of the assert still some random values like 7-8 but not 6 ?

Comment: Run your application with/without debugger and have a logger where the event can be raise. That way you will see without any test solution if it is a threading problem or a test solution problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost every time I have run into this issue it boils down to a race condition which is less likely to occur when you are debugging since you are slowing the execution down as you step through the code.

I would suggest adding debug or trace statements into the threads as they reach various stages of execution in order to identify where the race condition exists.